# Ajax unit test using Jasmine "TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine-jquery

```js
function download() {
     $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    }).done(function(data) {
         //processJasonData(data)
    }).fail(function () {
         //$fail();
    })
}
```

Im trying to make unit test with Jasmine using ajax but i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined".

```js
describe('AJAX check', function () {
    var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    it('test1', function () {
        spyOn($, "ajax");
        download(url);
        expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Anyone know how to resolve this problem ? And how to check when ajax is done?
I think I should use promises and deferred in this case, so can someone explain them to me?
(I`m using jQuery > 1.5)

rest code :

```js
function download(url) {
     $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
    }).done(function(data) {
         processJasonData(data)
    }).fail(function () {
         $fail();
    })
}

function $fail() {
    var error_msg_1 = '<div class="jumbotron text-center"><h1 style="size: 10px;color: red"> Faill </h1></div>';
    $('.tresc').html(error_msg_1);
}
function processJasonData(data) {
    var _data = $('.panel-group');
    var dataTemplate = $('#item_tmp').html();
     $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        _data.append(Mustache.render(dataTemplate, item));
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using " jasmine-ajax" plugin?

Comment: yes , I`m using this.

Comment: can you check weather "mock-ajax.js" loaded before see example here http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

Jasmines spyOn blocks the call to the function and "swallows" it (returning undefined). To make it pass the call to the spied function use `spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callTrough()`. [See Jasmine Docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E).

Comment: this test works! but how to make callFake to see if it`s done, or something else to check that?

Comment: You could use `.and.returnValue()` and use a fake object that has a `done` and a `fail`function.
To see if ajax calls work you can use the ajax-plugin http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html